# How can I get the last element of a string array with one line of code?

Tags: javascript

Right now, I get the last part of an URL to exclude the filename like this:

```
attachmentFileName = attachmentLink.split("/");
attachmentFileName = attachmentFileName[attachmentFileName.length-1];
```

it feels, as if I could do that in one statement only, but I can't figure out how.
Not a big deal, but i think it can be done more elegantly.

Comment: attachmentFileName = attachmentLink.split("/")[attachmentFileName.length-1];

Mind. Blown.

Comment: Are you on on NodeJS? Node has utilities for handling paths and URLs which are more robust than splitting on the slash.

Comment: Glubus that's really nice :) write it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method to retrieve last element of your splitted array:

```
attachmentFileName = attachmentLink.split("/").pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try to below code

```
attachmentFileName = attachmentLink.substring(attachmentLink.lastIndexOf("/")+1,attachmentLink.length);
```